# Cannot assign to immutable expression of type Swift

Tags: swift

I've seen several similar SO questions without much help,

I am trying to update `availabilityTimes` for Monday with `timesArray` using the function `updateDailyTimes`

Example of `availabilityTimes` and `timesArray`

```
 var availabilityTimes = [
         "Monday": [ "available" : true,
                     "times": [
                         ["startTime": "9:00 am", "endTime": "1:30 pm" ],
                         ["startTime": "2:30 pm", "endTime": "6:00 pm" ],
                         ["startTime": "7:30 pm", "endTime": "9:00 pm" ]
                     ]
         ],
         "Tuesday": [ "available" : true,
                     "times": [
                         ["startTime": "9:00 am", "endTime": "6:00 pm" ]
                     ]
                    ]
          ]




var timesArray = [
                    ["startTime": "9:00 am", "endTime": "1:30 pm" ],
                    ["startTime": "2:30 pm", "endTime": "6:00 pm" ],
                    ["startTime": "7:30 pm", "endTime": "9:00 pm" ]
                  ]
```

Here is my code, when I call the below the function, I get an error message `cannot assign to immutable expression of type [[String : String]]` in the code line `value["times"] as [[String : String]] = timesArray`

```
func updateDailyTimes(day: String, timesArray: [[String:String]]){

    guard var updatedTimes = self.availabilityTimes as? [String: AnyObject] else{
        return
    }

    for (key, var value) in updatedTimes {

        if key == day{
            for (key1, value1) in value as! [String : AnyObject]{
                if key1 as String == "times" {
                    value["times"] as [[String : String]] = timesArray // I get an error message in this line
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are fighting a Swift collection type with value semantics. Use a custom struct or class. It makes life a lot easier.

Comment: @vadian, Would be great if you could elaborate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my comment I mean a custom struct `Times` for the start and end times and a struct `DailyTimes` with the required properties and a mutating function to update the `Times` array:

```
struct Times {
    let start : String
    let end : String
}

struct DailyTimes {
    let weekday : String
    var available : Bool
    var times = [Times]()

    mutating func update(times : [Times]) {
        self.times = times
    }
}
```

Now create the `availableTimes` dictionary:

```
var availableTimes = ["Monday" : DailyTimes(weekday: "Monday", available: true, times: [Times(start: "9:00 am", end:"1:30 pm"),
                                                                                        Times(start: "2:30 pm", end:"6:00 pm"),
                                                                                        Times(start: "7:30 pm", end:"9:00 pm")]),
                      "Tuesday" : DailyTimes(weekday: "Tuesday", available: true, times: [Times(start: "9:00 am", end:"6:00 pm")])]
```

and the `timesArray` array:

```
let timesArray = [Times(start: "9:00 am", end:"1:30 pm"),
                  Times(start: "2:30 pm", end:"6:00 pm"),
                  Times(start: "7:30 pm", end:"9:00 pm")]
```

Since the `Times` array of `Monday` contains already the values of `timesArray` let's update `Tuesday`

```
availableTimes["Tuesday"]?.update(times:timesArray)
```

Finally prove it

```
print(availableTimes["Tuesday"]?.times)
```

Another improvement could be to use `DateComponents` instead of `String`s for the times.

Comment: Thanks, for the detailed explanation, I'll go with your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift, a `Dictionary` is a struct, which is a value type. Think of value types just like a primitive type such as `int`.

If you have this:

```
int a = 0
int b = a
```

Then b gets the value of a, they are not identical.

So when you are looping over the dictionary, your (key, value) pair are NOT actually what is in the dictionary, they just have the same value. It's also important not to mutate a value or reference while iterating over it. That can lead to weird bugs.

```
enum AvailabilityTimeMarker {
    case start
    case end
}
enum DayOfTheWeek: String {
    case monday = "Monday"
    case tuesday = "Tuesday"
    case wednesday = "Wednesday"
    case thursday = "Thursday"
    case friday = "Friday"
    case saturday = "Saturday"
    case sunday = "Sunday"
}

typealias Availability = [DayOfTheWeek : AvailabilityDay]
typealias AvailabilityDay = [String : Any]
typealias AvailabilityArray = [AvailabilityTime]
typealias AvailabilityTime = [AvailabilityTimeMarker : String]

var availabilityTimes: Availability = [
    .monday : [ "available" : true,
                "times": [
                    ["startTime": "9:00 am", "endTime": "1:30 pm" ],
                    ["startTime": "2:30 pm", "endTime": "6:00 pm" ],
                    ["startTime": "7:30 pm", "endTime": "9:00 pm" ]
        ]
    ],
    .tuesday : [ "available" : true,
                 "times": [
                    ["startTime": "9:00 am", "endTime": "6:00 pm" ]
        ]
    ]
]

var timesArray: AvailabilityArray = [
    [.start : "9:00 am", .end : "1:30 pm" ],
    [.start : "2:30 pm", .end : "6:00 pm" ],
    [.start : "7:30 pm", .end : "9:00 pm" ]
]

func updateDailyTimes(day: DayOfTheWeek, timesArray: AvailabilityArray) {

    let availabilities = self.availabilityTimes

    var newtimes = availabilities

    if var newDayAvailability = availabilities[day] {
        newDayAvailability["times"] = newtimes

        newtimes[day] = newDayAvailability

        self.availabilityTimes = newtimes// Since we're not using reference semantics, we have to change the entire value
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. Since I would like to update times for a particular day, should this `newtimes[key1] = timesArray as AnyObject` be `newtimes[day][key1] = timesArray as AnyObject` ? . When I try `newtimes[day][key1]` I get similar error `cannot assign to immutable expression of type Any`

Comment: As @vadian mentioned, we're fighting value semantics when the correct solution may be to either create your own struct that may wrap some dictionaries or use a class to get the benefit of reference semantics. If you're coming from objc, you can also use `NSDictionary` directly to get reference semantics, but you loose type safety.

Comment: @user44776, I've updated the code one last time, with a complete re-write showing a much simpler way to do it. I've also used some Swift features to make everything more clear.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed code, I went @vadian answer as it was easier to understand.

Comment: @user44776 His answer is definitely the right way to actually implement the code. I personally would do it that way, I was just trying to help you understand reference types since you'll come across them a lot in Swift.